# Internet only connects to certain websites (Google, Wikipedia, Facebook, Twitter)

Tags: wireless, connection, ip-address

I didn't change anything before this problem happened. I try to go to any other websites besides the ones listed in the title and it tells me the site's IP address could not be found.
I tried looking through the forums and finding an answer to this problem. The solutions end up not working for me.
The main hump I'm trying to get over is getting the IPv4 address for my router, but it just says "Unknown" next to the column.

I use Ubuntu 16.04. if you need any info, I'll do my best to copy them down from my computer.

Edit:
So, I attempted making a static IP address, but on reboot, I realized my device would not longer recognize any wireless networks. So, I had to delete that address. So far, that was the only way I could obtain an IPv4 address; without being able to connect to anything at all.

Comment: What it the DNS in `/etc/resolv.conf`? And if it is `127.0.0.1` can you give the output of `nmcli dev show | grep DNS`?

Comment: @xenoid This is the output:
`IP6.DNS[1]:                             2001:558:feed::1 IP6.DNS[2]:                             2001:558:feed::2`

Comment: Strange, you only have DNS for IPv6 (the same command lists IP4 and IP6 values on my 16.04).

Comment: @xenoid Actually you know what, the nameserver is not `127.0.0.1`, my mistake. It's `127.0.1.1`

Comment: That's the same thing :)

Comment: @xenoid Oh okay. Sorry, then. Thank you for attempting to help me, though.

Comment: Is your network interface enabled for IPv4? `ip address show` should list an `inet` address (and some `inet6` ones)

Comment: @xenoid There's only `inet6` addresses

Comment: See some comments [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314603/debian-and-centos-why-does-ipv6-prevail-over-ipv4)

Comment: Unplug your router for 10 seconds then plug it back in.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix That doesn't work. It's not a problem with the router. My computer is the only one with Ubuntu/Linux on it and all the other devices (including a computer with Windows on it) works. This computer is the only one having an issue.

Comment: @loaf OK. Then instead of flushing hardware DNS cache you can do software side on machine too with `sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches` and `sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clean start` as per this article: https://vitux.com/how-to-flush-the-dns-cache-on-ubuntu/

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Trying the first one gives me this `systemd-resolve: unrecognized option '--flush-caches'`, but the cache is already at 0.

Comment: A static IP address won't resolve this. Try making a LiveUSB & boot from it,to see if the problem persists.: Download the ISO for a version of your choice at https://ubuntu.com/download or for a 'flavour' with a different Desktop  download from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours . The ISO file should be checked for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 . Making the LiveUSB as per Ubuntu's publishers, is done following these instructions: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0

Comment: @loaf Could still be the router, if it malfunctioned just when your computer tried to grab an address. Have you rebooted or disconnected/reconnected the network on the Ubuntu machine?

Comment: @xenoid Yes, I have multiple times.

Comment: @xenoid That was my first thought too. Every time I had a similar problem cold booting the router fixed it.

Comment: @K7AAY Alright, so I made a LIVEUSB, booted it, and the problem is gone. I'm writing this message through the same computer. I'm looking at the settings and they all seem to be the same. I'm still not sure what the problem is, but I guess I know the solution is reachable?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I made a LIVEUSB for my current version (16.04), booted it, and saw that it worked perfectly fine. So, I copied down the connection information, went into my IPv4 settings, and manually inputted the settings into the IP address line, as well as the DNS settings. Then, my issue was solved.